# How to create interrupt after x seconds in Perl?

Tags: perl, timer, interrupt

Let me explain task with code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $t = 3;

eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    print "Start $t\n";
    alarm(10);
    sleep($t);  # instead of this I have some data that collect code
    alarm(0);
    print "done with $t\n";
};

if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";
    print "timeout\n";
}
```

Instead of `sleep` I have some code that push data to array. Array will be guaranteed filled by needed data during `x seconds.

Question: how to print array after `x` second, without using `sleep` (non-blocking way) ?

As far as I understand simplest way to set timer in perl is to use `$SIG{ALRM}`. But what to do if I don't need timer (can't use `sleep`), I just need to set one interrupt that must run after pre-defined amount of seconds ? Maybe I should use `SIGINT` for this task?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify?  what does your code example get wrong, if you replace the sleep with your actual data collecting code?

Comment: I think the problem in your code at the moment is that you collect your data (sleep) for only 3 seconds. You set your alarm timeout to 10 seconds. So, after the sleep of 3 seconds you wipe out the alarm, so you will never trigger it. I like the solution from @ikegami

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create your own interrupts, you need two threads of execution. One way to do this is to launch a child process that will signal its parent when some condition is met.

```
$SIG{USR1} = \&code_to_run_after_interrupt;
my $ppid = $$;          # process id of parent
if (fork() == 0) {
    # child process
    sleep 15;
    kill 'USR1', $ppid;
    exit;
}
... main execution thread
```

15 seconds after the `fork` call, your main script will stop what it's doing, execute the code in a subroutine named `code_to_run_after_interrupt`, and then resume the main thread of execution.

(I use `SIGUSR1` here because handling `SIGINT` may make you unable to use `Ctrl-C` to stop your program)

Answer (score 3):

That's the whole point of `alarm`! Just use a more suitable signal handler.

```
my @x;

$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
   print("$_\n") for @x;
   $SIG{ALRM} = undef;
};

alarm(10);

...
```